# No route found for omniauth developer strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I've just updated Omniauth from `0.2.6` to `1.1.1` in order to use the developer strategy. I've made my login link point to `/auth/developer` if the environment is development and `/auth/facebook` if production.

The Facebook strategy still works. When using the developer strategy, the link goes to the built-in Omniauth sign in page but returns a 404 when clicking sign in. This model does not use Devise.

**Routes file**

```
get "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
.
.
.
get '*a', :to => 'errors#routing'
```

**Omniauth initializer**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, [etc.]
  provider :developer if Rails.env.development?
end
```

**Log**

```
Started GET "/auth/developer" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-19 16:23:04 +0200
Started POST "/auth/developer/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-19 16:23:10 +0200
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/auth/developer/callback")
```

Comment: Do you have this file in your initializers folder? https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/developer.rb

Comment: No. That's not required to be in the initializers folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into this today in a new rails 4 application, I'm currently using this route as a workaround:

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: "sessions#create", via: [:get, :post]
```

Comment: Easily overlooked that the omniauth gem uses a `get` definition instead of `match`. Change that by above rule.